# Can not edit WordPress home page

Tags: wordpress, installation

I have just installed a WordPress site & all plugins I need. But unfortunately the home page of the site does not appear.

My WordPress project home page Edit screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings -> Reading -> select Homepage v6 from the dropdown infront of Front Page option

Answer (score 0):

First of all **create a page** in the wordpress admin end, the you would like to have as your front page.
Once you have **created your page,**
Inside the admin end go to the Appearance->Customize->Homepage Settings->Select the newly page that you just created in the homepage dropdown

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Please check your internet connection when your reload your tab/browser, because I think all JavaScript can't load perfectly.

Step 2. Change Your Browser then check it

Step 3. Deactivate your all plugin one by one then check when it's will be working. It's maybe Plugin conflict.

Step 3. Deactivate your theme then check it's working or not.

Then Please let me know your update.

Comment: I'm following all your steps, but it is not  working Such as changed the browser and all steps

Comment: Did you deactivate your all plugins ?